# Can we change the URL in Ajax script While Ajax is using in asp.net MVC ? But not to use any DIV?

Tags: ajax

Can we change the URL in Ajax script While Ajax is using in asp.net MVC ? But not to use any DIV?If YES then How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.location.assign('/ControllerName/ActionName');